# Insert based on conditions

Tags: mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to insert some data in mysql table. I have an option in opencart with option_id = 6, I want to insert into all products containing option_id=6 a new option with option_id=9.

```
 insert into oc_product_option (`option_id`)
 select 9
 where (SELECT `option_id` FROM oc_product_option WHERE `option_id` == 6);
```

is not working. how can we give a condition which does this in opencart?

**EDIT:** Here is some more information. I have One option Color 1 which is already assigned to thousands of products. I am trying to assign color 2 to all the products containing color 1.

1. Color1-  option id = 6
2. color2- option id = 9

In the opencart, mysql db tables are **oc_product_option and oc_product_option_value.**

in oc_product_option we have fields product_id, product_option_id(auto incremental-no need to update), option_id

So what I am doing is selecting the option id of color 2 -9 and assigning to products with option id = 6

Comment: if you are just inserting one column then why you need a select ? Provide some more information about what exactly you are trying with some sample data.

Comment: Added some details. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got it right your query must be like:

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_option (`product_id`,`option_id`)
 SELECT product_id,9
 FROM oc_product_option 
 WHERE `option_id` = 6;
```

Comment: oh this worked perfectly. do I do the same thing to product_option_value table to assign option values to products having that option? Like this  maybe? :

<code> INSERT INTO oc_product_option_value (`product_id`,`option_id`,`option_value_id`)
 SELECT product_id,9,option_value_id
 FROM option_value_id 
 WHERE `option_id` = 6;

</code>

Comment: not sure. what is your `oc_product_option_value` table structure? there mustn't be `product_id`

Comment: there is product_option_value_id which is incremental, product option id,product id, option id and option value id.

Comment: Are you sure? this table `oc_product_option_value` has 5 columns??

Comment: It actually has 20 columns [link] (http://prntscr.com/6zli1j) [/link] Check the screenshot

Comment: Lots of rows 22,328 rows to be exact. here is the screenshot of some of the records [link] (http://prntscr.com/6zm6bn)  [/link]